# How to set expiration date in Google OAuth 2.0 Client IDs , in google developer console portal

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am setting up my Google Oauth 2.0 client credentials but it is getting expired in 2-3 weeks. Can anyone tell from we can set expiration date of credentials in google developer console portal.
Credentials are for desktop app.

I have tried exploring all the details in google console but can not find option of setting up expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

The primary thing with Oauth that makes it secure is the fact that tokens expire.

An access token for example will expire after an hour so if anyone gets it they can only cause damage for a limited amount of time.

Refresh tokens can be used to request a new access token when the access token expires.

Refresh tokens can expire for a number of reasons

1. Your app is in the testing phase and there for the refresh token will expire after an hour.
2. your using a gmail scope and the user changes their password.
3. The user authorizes your application once you get a refresh token, they authorize it again and you get a second refresh token.  This can continue with up to 50 outstanding refresh tokens after that the first one will expire.  Always remember to store the latest refresh token.

There is no way to extend the life of any of the tokens this is configured by google in their authorization server.